# Pandas row filtering reproduces entire table and turns data into NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with several columns. I want to create a new dataframe which contains all the rows in the original dataframe for which the boolean value "Present" is True.

Normally the way you are supposed to do this is by calling `grades[grades['Present']]`, but I get the following unexpected result:

[image: Result]

It reproduces the entire dataframe, except changes the True values in the "Present" column to 1s (the False ones become NaNs).

Any idea why this might be happening?

Here is my full script:

```
import pandas as pd

# read CSV and clean up data
grades = pd.read_csv("2학기 speaking test grades - 2·3학년.csv")
grades = grades[["Year","Present?","내용 / 30","유찬성 / 40","태도 / 30"]]
grades.columns = [["Year","Present","Content","Fluency","Attitude"]]

# Change integer Present to a boolean
grades['Present']=grades['Present']==1

print(grades.head())
print(grades.dtypes)

print(grades[grades['Present']])
```

And terminal output:

```
  Year Present Content Fluency Attitude
0    2    True    30.0    40.0     30.0
1    2    True    30.0    40.0     30.0
2    2    True    30.0    40.0     30.0
3    2    True    30.0    40.0     30.0
4    2    True    30.0    40.0     30.0
Year          int64
Present        bool
Content     float64
Fluency     float64
Attitude    float64
dtype: object
    Year Present Content Fluency Attitude
0    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
1    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
2    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
3    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
4    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
5    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
6    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
7    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
8    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
9    NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
10   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
11   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
12   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
13   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
14   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
15   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
16   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
17   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
18   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
19   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
20   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
21   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
22   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
23   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
24   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
25   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
26   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
27   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
28   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
29   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
..   ...     ...     ...     ...      ...
91   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
92   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
93   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
94   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
95   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
96   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
97   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
98   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
99   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
100  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
101  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
102  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
103  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
104  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
105  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
106  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
107  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
108  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
109  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
110  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
111  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
112  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
113  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
114  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
115  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
116  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
117  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
118  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
119  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN
120  NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN

[121 rows x 5 columns]
```

Here is the CSV file. SE won't let me upload it directly, so if you paste it into your own CSV file you'll need to modify the Python code above to specify that it's in the EUC-KR encoding, like so: `pd.read_csv("paste.csv",encoding="EUC-KR")`

```
Year,Class,Year / class * presence (used to filter for averages),Present?,내용 / 30,유찬성 / 40,태도 / 30,Total,,,Averages (평균점),,
2,2,22,1,30,40,30,100,,,Grade distribution (점수 막대 그래프),,
2,2,22,1,30,40,30,100,,,The graph below includes the scores of all students in grades 2 and 3. ,,
2,2,22,1,30,40,30,100,,,아래 그래프에는 2·3학년에서 모든 학생의 점수가 정리됩니다.,,
2,2,22,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,30,30,90,,,Average scores (평균점),,
2,2,22,1,30,30,30,90,,,These averages only count students who were present for the test.,,
2,2,22,1,30,30,30,90,,,평균점에는 참석한 학생의 점수만 포함됩니다.,,
2,2,22,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,30,30,90,,,2학년 1반,,77.1
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,2학년 2반,,77.6
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,3학년 1반,,71.5
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,3학년 2반,,77.4
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,2,32,1,20,40,30,90,,,,,
2,2,22,1,20,30,30,80,,,,,
2,2,22,1,20,30,30,80,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,20,30,80,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,20,30,80,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,30,20,80,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,20,30,80,,,,,
2,1,21,1,20,30,30,80,,,,,
2,1,21,1,20,30,30,80,,,,,
2,1,21,1,30,30,20,80,,,,,
3,2,32,1,20,30,30,80,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,20,30,80,,,,,
3,2,32,1,20,30,30,80,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,30,20,80,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,20,30,80,,,,,
2,2,22,1,10,30,30,70,,,,,
2,2,22,1,20,20,30,70,,,,,
2,2,22,1,30,20,20,70,,,,,
2,2,22,1,20,20,30,70,,,,,
2,2,22,1,20,20,30,70,,,,,
3,2,32,1,30,10,30,70,,,,,
3,2,32,1,20,30,20,70,,,,,
3,2,32,1,20,20,30,70,,,,,
2,1,21,1,20,20,20,60,,,,,
2,1,21,1,10,20,30,60,,,,,
2,2,22,1,10,20,20,50,,,,,
2,2,22,1,10,10,30,50,,,,,
2,1,21,1,10,10,30,50,,,,,
2,1,21,1,20,20,10,50,,,,,
3,2,32,1,10,10,30,50,,,,,
3,2,32,1,10,10,30,50,,,,,
2,2,22,1,10,0,30,40,,,,,
2,1,21,1,10,0,30,40,,,,,
3,2,32,1,10,0,30,40,,,,,
3,2,32,1,10,10,20,40,,,,,
2,2,22,1,0,0,30,30,,,,,
2,1,21,1,0,0,30,30,,,,,
2,1,21,1,0,0,30,30,,,,,
3,2,32,1,0,0,30,30,,,,,
3,2,32,1,0,0,20,20,,,,,
2,1,21,1,0,0,10,10,,,,,
2,2,22,1,0,0,30,30,,,,,
2,2,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
2,2,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
2,1,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
2,1,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
2,1,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
2,1,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
3,2,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
3,2,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
3,1,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,20,30,80,,,,,
3,1,31,1,0,0,30,30,,,,,
3,1,0,0,,,,0,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,20,10,60,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,20,20,20,60,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,20,30,80,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,20,30,20,70,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,40,30,100,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,20,10,60,,,,,
3,1,31,1,20,10,20,50,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,20,30,80,,,,,
3,1,31,1,0,0,20,20,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,0,0,20,20,,,,,
3,1,31,1,20,10,10,40,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,30,30,90,,,,,
3,1,31,1,20,20,30,70,,,,,
3,1,31,1,30,20,10,60,,,,,
3,1,31,1,10,10,30,50,,,,,
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide data as text, not images so we can reproduce the issue. If I were to recreate your dataframe myself I will not have this problem.

Comment: runs ok on my system with the given dataset. Maybe your actual dataset is different?

Comment: I have updated my post with pasteable text.

Comment: Sorry, I get `Initializing from file failed` when using the .csv and code posted, but I can read the file fine with `csv.reader`.  Are your headers correct?

Comment: For some reason pasting in the text didn't reset the character encoding. It should load fine if you use `pd.read_csv("paste.csv",encoding="EUC-KR")`.

Comment: It wasn't that.  Pandas seems to have a bug on Windows and is trying to parse the Korean filename (not the content) with the wrong codec.  I actually saved the paste as UTF-8 and added that encoding to the `read_csv`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I went ahead and pasted the content directly from this post into a file named paste.csv (should have no encoding issues, right?) and was able to import it as a Pandas dataframe using the command I gave above with no problems. The strange filtering behavior, however, still persists.

Comment: I used the filename in your original code with Korean.  Pandas didn't like that.  `test.csv` works, but I see the same strange filtering.  When I create a dataframe manually, it works as expected.  I'm no pandas expert, but can't explain what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Seems like we're in the same place, and that there's an encoding compatibility issue with Pandas.

Comment: So the error is with `grades.columns = [["Year","Present","Content","Fluency","Attitude"]]` and the fix is to instead assign it to a 1D list `["Year","Present","Content","Fluency","Attitude"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to filter the Present column by True.
You can do it this way.

```
grades = grades[grades["Present"] == True]
```

If the boolean is stored as a string then use the double quotation.

```
grades = grades[grades["Present"] == "True"]
```

Comment: This produces the same output. Since the column is already a boolean the == bit is unnecessary.

Comment: Probably you need a double quotation on "True" in case the boolean is stored as a string. Otherwise the above code should work fine.

Comment: I will update my post when I get to my computer. The booleans are not strings.

Comment: @cs95 OP updated content.  I can reproduce the problem.  Instead of being rude, why don't you explain what is going on?

Comment: @MarkTolonen With all due respect, the post was updated way after my initial comment and my follow up. They seem to have updated their post so I have no more complaints.

Comment: @cs95 Can you reproduce the problem now?  I can so I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen The problem is effectively because they assigned `grades.columns` to `[["Year","Present","Content","Fluency","Attitude"]]` when it should've been a 1D list. Meaning they have a MultiIndex now and `grades['Present']` returns a DataFrame instead of a Series, making everything fail.

Comment: @cs95 This solution works. Thank you.